# Lemma 1.2 Brezis, the end of the proof, $x=\alpha\left(\alpha^{-1} x\right)+(1-\alpha) 0 \in C.$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I didn't understood why $(1-\alpha) 0 $ is needed in the part of $x=\alpha\left(\alpha^{-1} x\right)+(1-\alpha) 0 \in C,$ on the proof of Lema 1.2 of Brezis book of Functional Analysis. 
The Lemma 1.2 says:

> Let $C \subset E$ be an open convex set with $0 \in C.$ For every $x \in E$ we set:
>   $p(x)=\inf \left\{\alpha>0 ; \alpha^{-1} x \in C\right\}\tag{8}$
>   ($p$ is called the gauge of  $C$ or the Minkowski functional of $C$).
>
> Then $p$ satisfies $(1),(2),$ and the following properties:
>
> $\text{there is a constant $M$ such that $0 \leq p(x) \leq M\|x\| \quad \forall x \in E$}\tag{9},$
>   $$C=\{x \in E ; p(x)<1\}\tag{10}.$$
>
> Where $(1)$ and $(2)$ are the hypoteses of Hahn-Banach theorem, $(1)$ is $p(\lambda x) = p(x)$ and $(2)$ is $p(x + y) \leq p(x) + p(y).$

The proof of $(10)$ is:

> First, suppose that $x \in C ;$ since $C$ is open, it follows that $(1+\varepsilon) x \in C$ for $\varepsilon>0$ small enough and therefore $p(x) \leq \frac{1}{1+\varepsilon}<1 .$ Conversely, if $p(x)<1$ there exists $\alpha \in(0,1)$ such that $\alpha^{-1} x \in C,$ and thus $x=\alpha\left(\alpha^{-1} x\right)+(1-\alpha) 0 \in C.$

Why this part $(1-\alpha) 0$ is needed?

Comment: Note that $x(t) = t(\alpha^{-1}x)+(1-t)0$ for $0\leq t \leq 1$ is a parameterization of the line segment $[0,\alpha^{-1}x]$. So this is saying that some point in the interior of this segment lies in $C$ (i.e., there exists a $t$ in $(0,1)$ with $x(t)\in C$). I would say this term is included just so you can see it is part of a convex combination of the endpoints. Of course, it is zero, but it wouldn't be as clear without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why this part $(1−\alpha)0$ is needed?*

To emphasize the hypotheses: since $C$ is convex, $tu+(1-t)v\in C$ for all $u,v\in C$ and $t\in[0,1]$.

Taking $u=\alpha^{-1}x$, $v=0$ and $t=\alpha$ we obtain the desired result.

In short: As $C$ is convex, $\alpha\in [0,1]$, $\alpha^{-1}x\in C$ and $0\in C$, we have $\alpha (\alpha^{-1}x)+(1-\alpha)0\in C$.

---

Note that $\alpha^{-1}x\in C$ **doesn't** imply (necessarily) $\alpha (\alpha^{-1}x)\in C$ because $C$ isn't a vector space. In the context of the book, this is valid because $C$ is convex, $\alpha\in[0,1]$ **and** $0\in C$.